# When does type-level computation "happen" with type families?

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-level-computation

I'm trying to form an intuition about when (and how many times) type-level computation with type families "happens" in Haskell. For a concrete example, consider this typeclass for indexing into an [n-ary product](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html) using a type-level natural:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes
#-}
import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.SOP (I(..),NP(..)) -- identity functor and n-ary product from "sop-core"

data N = Zero | Succ N -- to be used as a kind

class Key (i :: N) (ts :: [Type]) where
    type Value i ts :: Type
    getValue  :: NP I ts -> Value i ts

instance Key Zero (t:ts) where
    type Value Zero (t:ts) = t
    getValue (I v :* _) = v

instance Key n ts => Key (Succ n) (t : ts) where
    type Value (Succ n) (t:ts) = Value n ts
    getValue (_ :* rest) = getValue @n rest

getValue' :: forall n ts. Key n ts => NP I ts -> Value n ts
getValue' = getValue @n @ts

getTwoValues :: forall n ts. Key n ts => NP I ts -> NP I ts -> (Value n ts, Value n ts)
getTwoValues np1 np2 = let getty = getValue @n @ts in (getty np1, getty np2)

main :: IO ()
main = do let np = I True :* I 'c' :* Nil
          print $ getValue     @(Succ Zero) np
          print $ getValue'    @(Succ Zero) np
          print $ getTwoValues @(Succ Zero) np np
```

My intuition is that typechecking that occurrence of `getValue` in `main` triggers the "traversal" of the type-level list at compile-time in search of the corresponding value type `Value (Succ Zero) '[Bool,Char]`. This traversal can be costly for large lists.

But what about `getValue'`? Does it trigger the "traversal" of the type level list one time, as before, or *two* times, one to check `getValue'` itself and another to check the `getValue` on which it depends?

And what about `getTwoValues`? In its signature there are two type family invocations `Value n ts`, even if they correspond to the exact same type. Do they get computed independently—slowing compilation—or is the computation "shared" at the type level?

Answer (score 2):

Haskell has "type erasure semantics". That is, assuming the compiler can resolve all types, then type inference "happens" at compile time; there is no computational effect at run time.

The compiler may not be able to 'resolve all types' under separate compilation: that is, it needs to postpone inference for this module until compiling some other module into which this is imported. At a worst case this might need postponing to execution time; and what's then getting executed is dictionary-passing/dictionary lookups.

The paper that explains type inference in modern GHC, including for type families, is OutsideIn(X). Your answer will be in there.

But seriously, why are you bothered about the performance internals of type "computation"? It is what it is. And your whole question has a nasty smell of expecting a procedural algorithm; whereas type solving behaves more like logic programming. Asking "when" it's executed is even less appropriate than asking "when" an expression is evaluated in a lazy language.

Comment: I phrased my  question badly: right now I'm only interested the performance of compile-time computation, and more on the "how many times" than on the "when". I’m working on a small extensible records library, and the compile times are quite long for big records. After tinkering a little, I noticed that I can sometimes avoid "duplicate computation" by using auxiliary type families, and that actually improved things. But I still don't have a good mental model for how compilation proceeds, what to avoid, and what other means exist for making things fast. Thanks for the OutsideIn(X) pointer.

Comment: As some very oblique evidence that GHC doesn't currently try to detect two type expressions are the same, see Trac #16070, and the linked discussion on github PR #158. On why even asking the question "when": OutsideIn(X) has something equivalent to (but not as indeterminate as) Robinson's unification algorithm used by Hindley-Milner; if it successfully unifies variable `alpha` with `beta`, does that count as solving once or twice? Necessarily they're duplicates (in a sense).